# Kendo UI for Angular 2 Upload Component - Upload Method

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-upload, kendo-ui-angular2

I am using [OpenStack Swift](http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/object-storage/) as a blob storage , and they are using the `PUT` method to create objects.

As for the frontend I am using **Kendo UI for Angular 2** for uploading of media.  The issue now is for Kendo UI upload service , its only using `POST` method.

As mention on their [site](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/upload/api/UploadComponent/#saveurl-string)

> The handler has to accept POST requests containing one or more fields with the same name as the original input name.

So I am wondering are there any way / configure that I am able to change the uploading method?

If there is currently no option avaliable , will telerik be implementing it? As I believe this is not the only case where the uploading method is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

This has now been implemented, so you could use the `saveMethod` and `removeMethod` options to specify the request type - [UploadComponent API](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/upload/api/UploadComponent/)

Comment: this page is not available. can you please help me with the correct URL

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to use `PUT`method for the `saveUrl` endpoint. Support for other methods will be added in a future version.

Comment: The latest version of the Upload adds support for setting a [saveMethod](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/upload/api/UploadComponent/#toc-savemethod)